# Will the zeros of linear combination of totally interlacing sequence of polynomials be real?

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, irreducible-polynomials

Question: For a sequence of real polynomials $p_k(z)$, if the zeros of each of them are real and distinct, and those zeros are totally interlacing. Will the zeros of linear combination of  $p_k(z)$ such as:

${\displaystyle\sum c_{k}p_k(z) }$

all be real ? Here, linear combination coefficient $c_{k}$ are all real.

Comment: What does "totally interlacing" mean?

Comment: Let us denote the increasing sequence of (real, distinct) roots of $p_k(z)$ by $r_{k, j}$:

i.e. $r_{k , j} < r_{k, j+1} $ 

totally interlacing means that the roots with number j belonging to disjoint intervals.

Comment: Sorry: I can't make sense of your explanation. Can you give a reference, please.

Comment: Steve Fisk's book: Polynomials, roots, and interlacing, available online: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612833

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It defines "interlacing" but not "totally interlacing".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. If you take the sequence of orthogonal polynomials for a certain measure, then the polynomials will have interlacing roots. Note that every polynomial is a linear combination of them. So probably you want positive linear combinations.

Added: In fact, the roots of orthogonal polynomials (for some measure) have the property that between any two roots of $f_m$ there is a root of $f_n$, for any $m$ and $n$. Is that what you mean by strong interlacing?

Comment: The roots of orthogonal polynomial will be interlacing, but under what condition, will they be totally interlacing ?

Comment: @david: maybe try with the Chebyshev polynomials ... there the roots are explicit

Comment: Are roots of Chebyshev polynomials  all real and distinct ?

Comment: @david: Yes, they are, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema

Comment: Thank you !  Those roots are indeed are real, distinct.